# Catch output from python subprocess

Tags: python, nginx, subprocess

I'm trying to catch the output from a command executed through python script.
I know that there is many examples about how to do this but I'm not able to get a solution.

**Example:**

This Example Works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['whoami'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = process.communicate()[0]
print 'STDOUT:{}'.format(stdout)
```

**Result:**

```
houhou@box:~/Documents$ python example.py
STDOUT:houhou
```

This doesn't work:

I need to run the following command: 'nginx -t'

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['nginx', '-t'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = process.communicate()[0]
print 'STDOUT:{}'.format(stdout)
```

Result:

```
houhou@box:~/Documents$ python example.py
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
STDOUT:
```

I don't know how to catch this output. It looks like that message indicating that nginx config is ok is printed before python can read it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Is it possibly being printed to `stderr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'zondo' rightly predicted in comment, 'nginx' send above messages to stderr, You can modify your code to read that message too-

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(['nginx', '-t'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> out,err = process.communicate()
>>> print out

>>> print err
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: you could use `output = check_output('nginx -t'.split(), stderr=STDOUT)`

Comment: thanks! the solution is like AlokThakur and Zondo says with 'stderr', i tryed before with 'stderr' but i did it in a wrong way...

Comment: @chrigu You may like to accept this answer, so that other user also will be benefited.